# For Each Loop Exits Immediately

Tags: vb6

I am converting a VB6 project to C#. I have come across some VB6 that I don't totally understand (and I don't have the ability to debug at all). It is a loop which exits immediately, before doing anything:

```
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
  Exit For
Next
```

Can anyone explain that? I'm sure it does something. I'm guessing it is assigning a variable, or something. If so, does it do it only once?

Comment: Is there a `Dim objSubFolder As something` before the For Each? Is there a `objSubFolder` used somewhere after the For Each? I don't remember much of VB6, but I was thinking that it might be a devious way to assign the first element in SubFolders to objSubFolder.

Comment: This was probably a stub that never got used.

Comment: @Paolo There is a objSubFolder declared before the loop (objSubFolder as folder) and it is used after the loop. My guess was the same as yours. A language-specific, devious assignment to that variable.

Comment: @Paolo Devious, yes. But also the *only* practical way, since accessing iterators explicitly in VB6 is a major pain in the *ss. Needless to say, this should have been properly documented in the source code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph sorry, I meant "devious" with the eye of somebody who has seen the last VB6 quite a few years ago. For all I know it could well be very idiomatic code and might have looked very obvious to me at the time I was using VB6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If objSubFolder exists outside the scope of the For Each (as per you comment), the code would be roughly the equivalent of this c#

```
var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\someFolder");
var firstFolder=folders.FirstOrDefault();
```

i.e. find the first subfolder of a given folder (if it exists).

Answer (score 4):

This code is mostly a complete no-op.  The only potentially significant effect this has one the code is that it will execute the `objFolder.SubFolders` property or method.  If this member has a note worthy side effect then this code could be significant.

It's the rough equivalent of the following C# code

```
object objSubFolder = null;
using (var e = objFolder.SubFolders.GetEnumerator()) {
  if (e.MoveNext()) {
    objSubFolder = e.Current();
  }
}
```

Note this is still not necessarily a 1-1 translation.

- if `objSubFolder` was previously defined in the method this would incorrectly overwrite it's value on an empty folder collection
- if the VB code had `Option Explicit Off` then you'd possibly need to convert `objFolder.SubFolders` to `dynamic` to get close to the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks Jared. I think it is assigning the first subdirectory object to the objSubFolder variable, which is declared as a folder earlier in the function.

Comment: It's absolutely **not** equivalent to that C# code. `objSubFolder` will still be in scope and available after the loop and will be assigned to the first subfolder (if there was one). Which is probably the point of the code. I think the C# equivalent would be `object objSubFolder; objforeach (objSubFolder in objFolder.SubFolders) {  break; } // objSubFolder is still in scope here and pointing to the first member`

Answer (score 3):

`Exit For` breaks out of the loop - basically C#'s `break` keyword. It does not look like this loop is doing anything practical..

Comment: It doesn’t look like it, but it *does*.